# Spritekit how do I measure impact force?

Tags: sprite-kit, game-physics

I'm using physics bodies in spritekit and I want to know what force a physics body is hit with.  how do I retrieve the amount of force that is being applied to an object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{


    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {
        contactPoint = contact.contactPoint;



        if((([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"A"] && [contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:@"B"] ) || ([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"B"] && [contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:@"A"])))
        {

           **contact.collisionImpulse is the collide force when two elements collide with each other**
        }

       }
}
```